# How does English 'lodge' come from Frankish *laubija by sound change?

Tags: english, etymology, french, sound-change

**[lodge](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lodge)** (etymonline)

> (n.) Middle English logge,
>   mid-13c. in surnames and place names; late 13c. as "small building or
>   hut," from Old French **loge** "arbor, covered walk; hut, cabin,
>   grandstand at a tournament" (12c.), from Frankish ***laubja** "shelter"
>   (cognate with Old High German louba "porch, gallery," German Laube
>   "bower, arbor"), from Proto-Germanic ***laubja-** "shelter." On a
>   widespread guess (backed by Watkins, OED) this likely originally meant
>   "shelter of foliage," or "roof made from bark," and is from the same
>   PIE root as leaf (n.).
>
> Modern spelling is from c. 1500. The specific sense "hunter's cabin"
>   is first recorded late 14c. Sense of "local branch of a society" is
>   first recorded 1680s, of Freemasons, from an earlier use of lodge as
>   "workshop of a group of masons" (mid-14c.). In the New World the word
>   was used of certain American Indian buildings (1805), hence lodge-pole
>   (1805) and lodge-pole pine (1859).

**[lodge](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lodge#English)** (wiktionary)

> From Middle English **logge**, from Old French **loge** ‎(“arbor, covered
>   walk-way”), Medieval Latin **lobia, laubia**, from Frankish ***laubija**
>   ‎(“shelter”), from Proto-Germanic ***laubijō** ‎(“arbour, protective roof,
>   shelter made of foliage”), from Proto-Germanic ***laubą** ‎(“leaf”), from
>   Proto-Indo-European ***lōubh-** ‎(“the outer parts of a tree, bark,
>   foliage”). Cognate with Old High German louba ‎(“porch, gallery”)
>   (German Laube ‎(“bower, arbor”)), Old High German loub ‎(“leaf,
>   foliage”), Old English lēaf ‎(“leaf, foliage”). Related to lobby,
>   loggia, leaf.

I wonder whether this sound change -b- > -g- happens regularly or not?

Comment: Very similar: [What explains the sound development from Latin -vi- to French -dg- ?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/14314)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Palatalized labials become palatal affricates (/pʲ/ > /tʃ/; /bʲ/ and /vʲ/ > /dʒ/; /mʲ/ > /ndʒ/) without emitting a preceding /j/.

in Early Old French from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_French#To_Early_Old_French

Comment: Do you have any other examples for /bj/ > /dʒ/ ?

Comment: @fdb: Italian cambiare ./. Modern French changer

Comment: Thanks so much! another example of /pʲ/ > /tʃ/ may be: French prochain < Vulgar Latin propeānus.